# Converting SLD to CPT

Tags: geoserver, symbology, convert, sld, cpt

I have different DEM data I want to publish with GeoServer using SLD files for styling. No problem so far, I created the files in QGIS and can use them for the WMS.

But additionally I would like to use gdaldem on the data to create overviews etc. Here comes my problem, gdaldem uses color palette table (CPT) files for styling and I would like to convert my SLD to CPT.

Is there a converter for SLD to CPT?